# No implicit return after existential check?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, promise

The following code:

```
db.query QUERY
    .then (val, err) ->
        if err?
            err
        else
            #process and return value
```

compiled to:

```
db.query(QUERY).then(function(val, err) {
    var arr; //various other var declarations
    if (err != null) {
        err; //useless expression!
    } else {
       //do stuff
    }
});
```

I had to add an explicit `return err` at line 4 of the original coffeescript to get the desired behavior...I was expecting the explicit return. I'm using coffeescript 1.8 with the `pg` and `promise` modules.
So why did the compiler output a useless statement instead of implicitly returning the error object (if present)? Nothing I can find in the documentation or on stack overflow speaks to this behavior, everything a google search turns up relates to how to *prevent* implicit returns, not when it fails.

EDIT: Per Benjamin Gruenbaum's answer below, here is the semantically valid code I meant to write. It steps around the problem. I've posted it here in case anyone else stumbles across this and is misusing promises also:

```
db.query(QUERY).then(
    (val) ->
        #handle value
    , (err) ->
        #handle err
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using promises wrong. Promises do not complicate your life - just like synchronous code you have `return` statements for normal flow control and `throw` statements for exceptional flow control.

Just like functions return a single value - `then` takes a single argument. Exceptional error handling is done in exceptions (called rejections).

In synchronous code you'd have:

```
try{  
  var val = db.query(QUERY);
  var arr; // various other var declarations
  // do stuff
} catch(e){
    // handle exception
}
```

Which translates with promises to:

```
db.query(QUERY).then(function(val) {
    var arr; //various other var declarations
    //do stuff
}).catch(function(err){
    // handle rejections (which are exceptions conceptually)
});
```

Comment: Fixed. Which eliminates the compiler error? obviously. Still, that was weird (or at least unexpected) output.

Comment: Also, realized what I meant to do was `.then (val) -> #do stuff; , (err) -> #handle err` with the error fn as the second arg to `.then()`...I misread the API docs

Comment: When I compile it locally it works fine, see: http://coffeescript.org/#try:db.query%20QUERY%0A%20%20%20%20.then%20(val%2C%20err)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20err%3F%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20err%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%205

Comment: Yeah, I had the same idiom (now replaced per your answer) somewhere else in my code and it behaved as expected. Not sure how that happened, new to coffee. Only reason I caught it was linter complained about the useless expression in the compiled output.

Answer (score 0):

Had the problem again and figured it out. Leaving this here in case anyone else stumbles upon the same issue. I switched to a new editor and didn't realize it defaulted to hard tabs for the auto-indent. The coffeescript compiler apparently gets thrown by a mix of tabs and spaces and skips the implicit return, meaning if you don't explicitly return you strand whatever expression was on the last line. Fixed it by switching to soft tabs.

Comment: Hm, you might want to file a bug report on that. Given that the control structures were correctly parsed and compiled, this should not happen.